# PHP: Skip word if character count < 3

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am using the following code to pull some keywords and add them as tags in wordpress.

```
if (!is_array($keywords)) {

    $count = 0;

    $keywords = explode(',', $keywords);

}

foreach($keywords as $thetag) {

    $count++;

    wp_add_post_tags($post_id, $thetag);

    if ($count > 3) break;

}
```

The code will fetch only 4 keywords, However on top of that, I want to pull ONLY if they are higher than 2 characters, so i dont get tags with 2 letters only.

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strlen($string)` will give you the lenght of the string:

```
if (!is_array($keywords)) {
    $count = 0;
    $keywords = explode(',', $keywords);
}

foreach($keywords as $thetag) {
   $thetag = trim($thetag); // just so if the tags were "abc, de, fgh" then de won't be selected as a valid tag
   if(strlen($thetag) > 2){
      $count++;
      wp_add_post_tags($post_id, $thetag);
   }

   if ($count > 3) break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to check the length.

> `int strlen ( string $string )`
>
> Returns the length of the given string.

```
if(strlen($thetag) > 2) {
    $count++;
    wp_add_post_tags($post_id, $thetag);
}
```